# Error while zipping multiple images from array of urls using JSZip and StreamSaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jszip

I want to zip multiple images from an array of urls. Those urls are fetched from a `json` file. For zipping I am using `JSZip` and `Stream Saver`. Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('the url which returns json', {}, function (data) {
    let imageUrl = new Array();
    let resources = data.resources;

    for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
      //actual image url
      let imageString = resources[i].public_id; 
      imageUrl.push(imageString);
    }

    //start zipping on submit
    $("#proceed").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      //initialize JSZip
      const zip = new JSZip();

      //initialize stream saver
      if (!window.WritableStream)
        streamSaver.WritableStream = ponyfill.WritableStream || WritableStream;

      const imageSaver = streamSaver.createWriteStream('Zipped_Images.zip').getWriter();

      /**
       * images will be zipped inside the image-file directory
       */
      var image_folder = zip.folder("Zipped_Images");
      var imageCount = 0;

      imageUrl.forEach(function (image, i) {

        //getting image name from url
        let filename = (i + 1) + "_" + image.match(/(?<=\/)[^\/\?#]+(?=[^\/]*$)/)[0] + ".jpeg";

        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(image, function (err, data) {
          //****here I get the error**
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          /**
           * adding images to zip folder 
           */
          image_folder.file(filename, data, {
            binary: true
          });
          imageCount++;
          if (imageCount == imageUrl.length) {

            zip.generateInternalStream({
              type: 'blob'
            }).on('data', function (data, metadata) {
              imageSaver.write(data);
            }).on('error', function (e) {
              showError(e);
            }).on('end', function () {
              imageSaver.close();
            }).resume();
          }
        })
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-y3o0Z5TJF1UsKjs/jS2CDkeHN538bWsftxO9nctODL5W40nyXIbs0Pgyu7//icrQY9m6475gLaVr39i/uh/nLA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.1.0/jszip-utils.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-3WaCYjK/lQuL0dVIRt1thLXr84Z/4Yppka6u40yEJT1QulYm9pCxguF6r8V84ndP5K03koI9hV1+zo/bUbgMtA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-polyfills@0.1.43/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web-streams-polyfill@2.0.2/dist/ponyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/streamsaver@2.0.5/StreamSaver.js"></script>
```

As I click the `#proceed button` I see these errors in my console for some urls at starting. **`But after some times zipping starts and when I open zipped file, after download completed, some images are corrupted.`**

```js
GET https://image-url net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
u.getBinaryContent @ jszip-utils.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.js:51
(anonymous) @ main.js:46
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2

main.js:62 Error: InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'arraybuffer').
    at XMLHttpRequest.f.onreadystatechange (jszip-utils.min.js:1)
```

Is this because of any looping issue? Because I am calling the url inside a loop and the loop is executing fast, but the urls are not loaded until then. I am running this from `localhost`.